# Ajax Tab Container loads the first tab always when fire an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, updatepanel

I have an AJAX tab container that contains two tab panels.

The problem when I fire an event on the second tab it reloads the first tab.

Any help? Suggestions? below is a sample of the aspx code

```
       <AJAX:TabContainer runat="server" ID="tcMain" ActiveTabIndex="0">
                    <AJAX:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tpTab1" TabIndex="1">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Tab1
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div runat="server" id="div1">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTab1" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                       //entry and events 
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </AJAX:TabPanel>
                    <AJAX:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tpTab2" TabIndex="2">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Tab2
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div runat="server" id="div2">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTab2" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        // entry and events
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                   </AJAX:TabPanel>
            </AJAX:TabContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is because of page post-back happening.you can manage the data using ViewState property this link may solve your issue [HElP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bc4f7459-4917-4034-957c-6c7f871fa109/on-postback-losing-ajax-tab-panel-activetab-index-in-webpart?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)

.